# How to handle masked areas of a conformally coated board?

Tags: conformal-coating

If I'm designing a board which will be exposed to humidity, temperature swings below dew point, etc and I decide to conformally coat the board to help protect it. How should you treat areas that need to be masked off?

Connectors obviously shouldn't be coated, as well as pcb features such as pogo-pin lands but now those parts of the assembly are exposed to the air.

For connectors, is the best mitigation to use gold flashed terminals and to use ENIG(and friends) for exposed PCB features? Or is there a better way?